# Combined diacritics don't combine

Tags: fontforge

I have a font where combined diacritics don't combine. Some applications **(Adobe Illustrator**) render the font correctly, one application shows the characters separately. Unfortunately, this application lives on a server outside of my control, which makes testing difficult. When I switch to another font **(Arial Unicode MS)**, the combined diacritics are shown correctly. This application does not support OpenType fonts.

For example, `U+00EA` (ê) plus `U+0323` (dot below) should be rendered as an e with circumflex above and dot below (ệ), but one application renders it as ê. with the dot after the ê **(the dot is at the correct vertical position)**.

When I use `View->Combinations->Ligatures` in FontForge, the combination of these two glyphs is shown correctly.

Not being a font designer, I'm a bit lost. What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Combining diacritics is a nice font feature but it's not universally supported. The application in question probably just doesn't support modern font features.

Combining diacritics should be designed with this in mind. Give them zero advance-width, and position the diacritic left of the glyph start position, so that it will naturally fall over/under the previous character. Unfortunately you can't get it perfectly positioned against that character; but if you make it look good over/under an *a*, it will probably be at least legible with *i*, *w*, etc.

This is really a stopgap measure in case of poor software, and it won't always work. For instance, high diacritics above capitals or tall lowercase letters will run into trouble.